# Can I get iOS UINavigationController in same status?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController in my app which contains questions, mcqs answer and their relevant scores.

I am pushing this controller in other controller , i.e

```
QuestionViewController *questionController = [delegate getQuestionScreen];


    // If Iphone/iPod Touch
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        // If iPhone 5 or new iPod Touch
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568){
            questionController = [[QuestionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuestionViewController" bundle:nil];

        } else{
            // Regular iPhone
            questionController = [[QuestionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuestionViewController_iPhone4" bundle:nil];

        }
    }


    questionController.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:questionController animated:NO];
```

When I am on this Controller,I open side Menu (like facebook) and selection option of New Controller, say HelpController...

```
 DemoViewController *demoController = [[DemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpViewController_iPhone4" bundle:nil];


        UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
        NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:demoController];
        navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
        [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```

When I go back to previous Screen of QuestionViewController, I have to create new object of that controller, in result of which I lost all my calculation and old data as it laods new.

How can I store old Controller to navigate that again or re-use in that particular status.

If anything is not clear regarding question, ask me.......

Comment: Is your QuestionViewController is the root View and the calculations which you are performing are on QuestionViewController?

Comment: I am not getting your question as well as why you are creating two object of same view controller for iPhone 4 and 5. I really don't know can you elaborate this

Comment: I am not sure about this solution as I didn't get your question properly, but you can go with singleton object.

Comment: Question VIew Controller is not root view controller, I heirachy is

1. AppDelegate, 2. Container (the side menu) 3. DemoViewController ,,,,,,AFter demo screen I am pushing views in it, like question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do this:

```
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:demoController];
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Because it asks the navigation controller to throw away all of the current views.

Instead, push the new controller.

If for some reason you can't just push it, create an instance variable (`NSArray`) and use it to store `navigationController.viewControllers` before you replace it, then you can restore it later.

Comment: Let me try if any issue or query, I would ask you. Thanks for reply.

Comment: both are different, should I explain you more about heir achy of App.

Comment: Different? After the demo do you want to go back to exactly where you were before or to somewhere else?

Comment: I saved QuestionViewController in array and retrieving the last object. Thanks @Wain